# Inheriting this scope in nested object

Tags: javascript

I call the following method in JS:

```
app.execute({
   first: function() {
      console.log('executed');
      oneMethod(); // function undefined
      app.oneMethod(); // works
      this.oneMethod(); // works when I exract app object into this variable
   },
   second: function() {

   }
});
```

The app object looks like this:

```
var app = function() {
   var oneMethod = function() {

   };    
   var secondMethod = function() {

   };
   var execute = function(first, second) {
      var obj = new first();
   };
   this.oneMethod = oneMethod;
   this.secondMethod = secondMethod;
   this.execute = execute;
};
```

So, the first code sits in HTML, and the second is external library. I do something using that external library's methods inside the `execute()` argument. I want to do this, so that I don't have any conflicts in global namespace - there's only `app` variable, and its methods are available only in its argument object.

So when I create an object with `new` keyword, I want to have the same namespace in its constructor, as I do in place where I create this object.

Is this possible? Are there better ways?

Comment: Is your current code working ?

Comment: Use bind() to set the context to `app` [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't want `app` to be a constructor, but rather an object itself. You can easily construct it using the revealing module pattern (an object-returing IIFE):

```
var app = (function() {
    function oneMethod() {
        …
    }
    function secondMethod() {
        …
    }
    function execute(first, second) {
        var obj = new first();
    }
    return {
        oneMethod: oneMethod,
        secondMethod: secondMethod,
        execute: execute
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

We make a namespace `app`, bind methods to namespace such that those methods do not leak to global. I.e. `method` is not defined(requirement#1) and `app.method()` "works" (requirement#2)

```
app = {
  execute(First, Second) {},
  method(){}
};
```

We create an instance of `First` in `app.execute()`, hope that "have the same namespace in its constructor" such that `this.method` in `First` constructor be the same `app.method`(requirement#3). [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/natcrL6y/)

```
app = {
  execute(First, Second) {
    var object = Object.create(app);
    First.call(object);
  },
  method() {}
};
```

If there are secret variables which `app.method` depends on

```
app = (function () {
  var secret = 'variable';
  return {
    execute(First, Second) { /*...*/ },
    method() { return secret }
  };
}());
```

Note that we used "[a shorter syntax for method definitions on object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)" which is introduced since ES2015. (Thx, @Bergi)
We can transform the ES6 solution into ES5 like that

```
app = {
  execute: function (First, Second) {
    var object = Object.create(app);
    First.call(object);
  },
  method: function () {}
};
```

Comment: If you use ES6 in your answers without the question being tagged accordingly, please don't forget to put a notice about it (and the necessity to transpile it).